# How can I implement WS-Security 1.0 in PHP5 using certificates?

Tags: php, soap, ws-security

I have found very interesting the answer to [how to implement ws-security 1.1 in php5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987907/how-to-implement-ws-security-1-1-in-php5)
but I need to use certificates to authenticate the connection to the WebService.

Does anyone know a way to do such a thing on PHP5?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I`m in the same trouble.
What I found by now were two libraries, but I had no luck by now. http://code.google.com/p/wse-php/ http://phpwebservices.blogspot.com/ If you have any success I`ll be very grateful if you to share it.

Comment: Hey Julian, many thanks for the info. I'm downloading wse-php to give it a try. I've also found interesting the following extension [PHP wssecurity] (www.docweb.provincia.pu.it/download/wssecurity.html) I'll be sharing my discoveries.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my script. With this script it returns me:

An error occurred when verifying security for the message.
And i Want to find a way to debug this message.
The .pem file is generated from the key file signed certificate and the ca-file.
.crt is ca-certificate. I have no information what server expect exactly.......
Later I`ll check server holders for more info and could they provide me with some debug information

```
require('wse/soap-wsa.php');
require('wse/soap-wsse.php');
define('PRIVATE_KEY', dirname(__FILE__).'/cert/B_13925_Cert.pem');
define('CERT_FILE', dirname(__FILE__).'/cert/Generali-Root.crt');

class mySoap extends SoapClient {

function __doRequest($request, $location, $saction, $version) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($request);

    $objWSA = new WSASoap($dom);
    $objWSA->addAction($saction);
    $objWSA->addTo($location);
    $objWSA->addMessageID();
    $objWSA->addReplyTo();

    $dom = $objWSA->getDoc();

    $objWSSE = new WSSESoap($dom);
    /* Sign all headers to include signing the WS-Addressing headers */
    $objWSSE->signAllHeaders = TRUE;

    $objWSSE->addTimestamp(3600);

    /* create new XMLSec Key using RSA SHA-1 and type is private key */
    $objKey = new XMLSecurityKey(XMLSecurityKey::RSA_SHA1, array('type'=>'private'));

    /* load the private key from file - last arg is bool if key in file (TRUE) or is string (FALSE) */
    $objKey->loadKey(PRIVATE_KEY, TRUE);

    /* Sign the message - also signs appropraite WS-Security items */
    $objWSSE->signSoapDoc($objKey);

    /* Add certificate (BinarySecurityToken) to the message and attach pointer to Signature */
    $token = $objWSSE->addBinaryToken(file_get_contents(CERT_FILE));
    $objWSSE->attachTokentoSig($token);

    $request = $objWSSE->saveXML();
    $f = fopen('debug.txt','w');
    fwrite($f,print_r($request,true));
    fclose($f);
    return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $saction, $version);
     }
    }


   $soap_url = 'https://test.domain.bg:9443/GPM/GPMPolicyService.svc/gpm?wsdl';
   $soap_client = new mySoap($soap_url);
   $getNomenclaturesRequest = new getNomenclaturesRequest(array(1,2,3,4));
   $request = new GetNomenclatures($getNomenclaturesRequest);
   try {
          $out = $soap_client->GetNomenclatures($request);
         var_dump($out);die();
    } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    //    var_dump($fault);
    }
    header('Content-type:text/xml');
    print_r(file_get_contents('debug.txt'));
```