# PHP Soap Client does not make request

Tags: php, soap

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '0');
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', '0');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 123456);
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 100);

$client = new SoapClient( 'http://#########:9999/CardExternalService.svc?wsdl', array( 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 'trace' => 1, 'local_cert' => 'something.pem' ) );

try {
    $client ->__soapCall( 'getFullCardData', array( 'CardUniqueID, EndClientData' ) );
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

when I execute function, apache downs. I don't know what happens, I tried nusoap, native one, WSO2 but same result. php does everything except certificate request. i don't even know how to explain. i cannot see any error.

```
Warning:  SoapClient::SoapClient() [<a href='soapclient.soapclient'>soapclient.soapclient</a>]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;http://########:9999/CardExternalService.svc?wsdl&quot; in C:\\wamp\\www\\Soap\\index.php on line 9

Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://########:9999//CardExternalService.svc?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://########:9999/CardExternalService.svc?wsdl"\n in C:\\wamp\\www\\Soap\\index.php on line 9
```

I think this is last stem, when i tried nusoap, there was a soap version problem, (text/xml & text/soap+xml), wso2 is not supported for 5.3 already. native client does everything, but for the last step, apache downs. zend client can not be used, cause my Core is old one and there are version disbalancing..

any kind of help, will be appreciated...

PS. they got microsoft IIS server with .NET WPF service and i try to communicate with CentOS, apache, PHP 5.2

Comment: Have you tried loading the page you request manually? http://#########:9999/CardExternalService.svc?wsdl

Comment: yes, everything work fine, i found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676075/how-can-i-implement-ws-security-1-0-in-php5-using-certificates this article, but there are so many errors in library, may be depreciated too. my only problem is that, i need WS security php soap libs. my authentication is without user & pass, but with certificates only.