# PHP Authentication for SOAP webservice with ws-security

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, ws-security

I have to use a web service that requeires authentication with ws-security like that:

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="Example-1">
            <wsse:Username>MYUSERNAME</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">MYPASSWORD</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">NONCE==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.000Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

How can I do this kind of authentication with PHP SoapClient?

Answer (score 0):

You have to build it yourself.

See this example https://gist.github.com/silasrm/a57a1e3af165cb43644b712192625a3b

To avoid dead links, I'm posting the code here:

```
<?php

/**
 * This class can add WSSecurity authentication support to SOAP clients
 * implemented with the PHP 5 SOAP extension.
 *
 * It extends the PHP 5 SOAP client support to add the necessary XML tags to
 * the SOAP client requests in order to authenticate on behalf of a given
 * user with a given password.
 *
 * This class was tested with Axis, WSS4J servers and CXF.
 *
 * @author Roger Veciana - http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/author/233806.html
 * @author John Kary <johnkary@gmail.com>
 * @author Alberto Martínez  - https://gist.github.com/Turin86/5569152
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987907/how-to-implement-ws-security-1-1-in-php5
 */
class WSSoapClient extends SoapClient
{
    private $OASIS = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01';

    /**
     * WS-Security Username
     * @var string
     */
    private $username;
    
    /**
     * WS-Security Password
     * @var string
     */
    private $password;
     
    /**
     * WS-Security PasswordType
     * @var string
     */
    private $passwordType;
      
    /**
     * Set WS-Security credentials
     * 
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     * @param string $passwordType
     */
    public function __setUsernameToken($username, $password, $passwordType)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->passwordType = $passwordType;
    }
       
    /**
     * Overwrites the original method adding the security header.
     * As you can see, if you want to add more headers, the method needs to be modified.
     */
    public function __call($function_name, $arguments)
    {
        $this->__setSoapHeaders($this->generateWSSecurityHeader());
        return parent::__call($function_name, $arguments);
    }
        
    /**
     * Generate password digest.
     * 
     * Using the password directly may work also, but it's not secure to transmit it without encryption.
     * And anyway, at least with axis+wss4j, the nonce and timestamp are mandatory anyway.
     * 
     * @return string   base64 encoded password digest
     */
    private function generatePasswordDigest()
    {
        $this->nonce = mt_rand();
        $this->timestamp = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
        
        $packedNonce = pack('H*', $this->nonce);
        $packedTimestamp = pack('a*', $this->timestamp);
        $packedPassword = pack('a*', $this->password);
        
        $hash = sha1($packedNonce . $packedTimestamp . $packedPassword);
        $packedHash = pack('H*', $hash);
        
        return base64_encode($packedHash);
    }
    
    /**
     * Generates WS-Security headers
     * 
     * @return SoapHeader
     */
    private function generateWSSecurityHeader()
    {
        if ($this->passwordType === 'PasswordDigest')
        {
            $password = $this->generatePasswordDigest();
            $nonce = sha1($this->nonce);
        }
        elseif ($this->passwordType === 'PasswordText')
        {
            $password = $this->password;
            $nonce = sha1(mt_rand());
        }
        else
        {
            return '';
        }

        $xml = '
<wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="' . $this->OASIS . '/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
    <wsse:Username>' . $this->username . '</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="' . $this->OASIS . '/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#' . $this->passwordType . '">' . $password . '</wsse:Password>
    <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="' . $this->OASIS . '/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">' . $nonce . '</wsse:Nonce>';
        
        if ($this->passwordType === 'PasswordDigest')
        {
            $xml .= "\n\t" . '<wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="' . $this->OASIS . '/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">' . $this->timestamp . '</wsu:Created>';
        }
        
        $xml .= '
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>';
        
        return new SoapHeader(
            $this->OASIS . '/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd',
            'Security',
            new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML),
            true);
    }
}
```

and how to make the call:

```
$username = "XXXX";
$password = "YYYY";
$passwordType = "PasswordText";
        
$url = "https://www.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.wsdl";
$client = new WSSoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0));
$client->__setUsernameToken($username, $password, $passwordType);

$function_name = "GetSomeStuff";        // name of the function/request
$arguments = array(
     "GetSomeStuff" => array(           // variables depending on the function/request
         "ID" => "XYXYXYX",
         "XX" => ...
      )
 );

$result = $client->__call($function_name, $arguments);
```